# Remove the middle name from a full name, and start the names with capital letters

Tags: c#

I need to get the middle name or names of an entire name, for example: "mikael da conceição souza luz". - The result should come out with: "mikael light".
However, I also need to leave the result the same exit with the first letters in capital letters, example: "Mikael Luz".
I have the following code as source code and the code after that is the test class, where the expected result has to hit the source code.
can you help me?
Thank you.

```
namespace TesteArgo
{
    public class teste3
    {
        //ESSA FUNÇÃO É A QUE EU USO PARA TRANSFORMAR LETRAS MINUSCULAS EM MAIUSCULAS NO NOME.
        public string NomesComPrimeirasLetrasMaiusculas(string nome)
        {
        string[] excecoes = new string[] { "e", "de", "da", "do", "dos" };
        var palavras = new Queue<string>();
        foreach(var palavra in nome.Split(' '))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(palavra))
            {var emMinusculo = palavra.ToLower();
             var letras = emMinusculo.ToCharArray();
             if (!excecoes.Contains(emMinusculo)) letras[0] = char.ToUpper(letras[0]);
             palavras.Enqueue(new string(letras));
            }
        }
        return string.Join(" ", palavras);
        }


        //ESSA É A FUNÇÃO QUE USO PARA REMOVER OS NOMES DO MEIO DE UM NOME COMPLETO, PORÉM NÃO CONSIGO APLICAR AS DUAS FUNÇÕES JUNTAS.
        public string RemoverNomeDoMeio(string nome)
        {   string nomeCompleto = "cleber reis pereira";
            string primeiroNome = "";
            string sobreNome = "";
            string[] arrayNome = nomeCompleto.Split(' ');

            if (arrayNome[arrayNome.Length - 2].Length < 4)
            {
             //percorro o array e enquanto o campo não for o penúltimo eu incluo na variável primeiroNome
             for (int i = 0; i < arrayNome.Length - 2; i++)
             {
                  primeiroNome += arrayNome[i] + " ";
             }

             //percorro o array a partir do penúltimo campo e incluo os valores na variável sobreNome
             for (int i = arrayNome.Length - 2; i <= arrayNome.Length - 1; i++)
             {
                 sobreNome += arrayNome[i] + " ";
             }

             //aqui é só colocar a saída dos dados, lembrando de eliminar os espaços em branco no início e 
             //fim das variáveis
            }

            teste3 teste = new teste3();
            var test1 = teste.NomesComPrimeirasLetrasMaiusculas(nome);          
            
            return test1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Judging by the `foreach` this is C#

Comment: Also by the liberal use of `public`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like C#, so I'll answer this in C#.

Split the name based on spaces, and take the first and last element. I use the ternary condition here, but a simple if-else structure would have worked just as well.

```
var arrayNome = nomeCompleto.Split(' ');
var primeiroNome = arrayNome.Count() != 0? arrayNome[0] : String.Empty; // Empty if there are no words (nomeCompleto is empty).
var sobreNome = arrayNome.Count() > 1? arrayNome[arrayNome.Count()-1] : String.Empty; // Empty if there is only one word or no words at all.
```

Next, return both names (if not empty) with first letter capitalized. There's a handy out-of-the-box function for this.

```
return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(String.Join(" ", primeiroNome, sobreNome));
```